# Is there a way to prevent alt-tab from raising all windows of an application?

Tags: unity, application-switcher

I have several gvim windows open and one Firefox window. Using Alt-Tab to switch to Firefox works as expected. Using it to go back to gvim does return focus to the gvim window I wanted to write in, but it also raises all other gvim windows (on the current virtual desktop) above the Firefox window.

Is there a way to reconfigure window switching so that all irrelevant gvim windows are left alone and I am able to switch between Firefox and a selected gvim window only?

I use Ubuntu 11.10 on the machine in question.

Comment: Is this still a problem for you in 13.04?  It is working the way you want on my fresh install.  Ironically, I want the opposite. :)

Comment: I'm on 12.04 LTS, but apparently, it seems to work the way I wanted it to. I'm sorry that it's not the way you want the WM to work, but if you add an answer "fixed in the meantime in 12.04 (and possibly newer)", I'll accept it as you basically drew my attention to the fact that it was, in fact, fixed in the meantime.

Answer (score 0):

You can use another trick to solve your prob minimize all windows that are idle to you. Then on the panel you can click the middle button of the the mouse that would switch between the two windows that are not idle

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, maythux, but I often work with tens of open windows (not a problem under Gnome 2, my environment of choice before) so it's not a practical option.

Answer (score -1):

If you have multiple windows open of a particular program, they will be grouped in single icon when you use `Alt+Tab`, as shown below. I have 3 LibreOffice Writer windows open, but they are grouped in a single icon:

[image: Showing 3 LibreOffice Writer windows grouped into one]

If you go to the LibreOffice icon and then press `Alt+backtick` (backtick = `, the key above tab), you see the preview of all the windows. You just have to keep pressing`Alt+backtick` unless it points to the window you want to open.

[image: Expanded view of the windows]

Comment: I don't think we understand each other. I don't care much about the icons or window preview: what I want is to be able to switch back and forth between a specific gvim and Firefox window, without having to see all the other gvim windows in front of Firefox every time I switch back to any gvim window.